# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() at com.example.sdl.change_password.<init>(change_password.java:30)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Have tried all the answers for the similar question but couldn't solve the problem please guide for this code.

I am trying to pass content from one actitvity to another; the content is passed but `ref.child(domain)` in `change_password` is unable to get the path.

package com.example.sdl;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button Login;
     EditText domain,pass,subdomain,profession,branch,rollno;
    FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  public  String sdomain,ssubdomain,sprofession,sbranch,srollno,spass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);

        domain = (EditText) findViewById((R.id.domain));
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        subdomain = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subdomain);
        profession = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profession);
        branch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.branch);
        rollno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rollno);



        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openadmin();
            }
        });




    }

    public void openadmin(){


            sdomain=domain.getText().toString();
            ssubdomain=subdomain.getText().toString();
            sprofession=profession.getText().toString();
            sbranch=branch.getText().toString();
            srollno=rollno.getText().toString();
            spass=pass.getText().toString();

        DatabaseReference ref=database.getReference().child(sdomain).child(ssubdomain).child(sprofession).child(sbranch).child(srollno);

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String saved_pass= dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();

                if (sprofession.equals("admin")) {

                    if (saved_pass.equals(spass)) {
                        open_admin();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PASSWORD IS WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if (sprofession.equals("student")){

                        if (saved_pass.equals(spass)) {
                            open_student();

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PASSWORD IS WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO USER FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



    }
    public void  open_admin(){
        Intent login = new Intent(this, main_admin.class);
        startActivity(login);
    }
    public void open_student(){
        Intent login =new Intent(this, Student.class);
        login.putExtra("domain",sdomain);
        login.putExtra("subdomain",ssubdomain);
        login.putExtra("profession",sprofession);
        login.putExtra("branch",sbranch);
        login.putExtra("rollno",srollno);
        login.putExtra("pass",spass);
         startActivity(login);
    }
}


package com.example.sdl;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Student extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView student_text;
    Button change_pass;
    String sdomain,ssubdomain,sprofession,sbranch,srollno,spass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);

       student_text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.student_text);


        change_pass=(Button) findViewById(R.id.change_pass);

        Toast.makeText(this, ssubdomain, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        change_pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                change_pass();

            }
        });

    }

         public  void change_pass(){


             sdomain=getIntent().getExtras().getString("domain");
             ssubdomain=getIntent().getExtras().getString("subdomain");
             sprofession=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profession");
             sbranch=getIntent().getExtras().getString("branch");
             srollno=getIntent().getExtras().getString("rollno");
             spass=getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass");
            Intent change = new Intent(this,changepass.class);
             change.putExtra("domain",sdomain);
             change.putExtra("subdomain",ssubdomain);
             change.putExtra("profession",sprofession);
             change.putExtra("branch",sbranch);
             change.putExtra("rollno",srollno);
             change.putExtra("pass",spass);
             startActivity(change);

    }
}
package com.example.sdl;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class changepass extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        EditText oldpass,newpass;
        Button changepas;
        String sdomain,ssubdomain,sprofession,sbranch,srollno,spass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_changepass);


             oldpass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.oldpass);
            newpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.newpass);
            changepas= (Button) findViewById(R.id.changepas);

        changepas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                verify_change();

            }
        });

    }

        public void  verify_change(){



            final String voldpass=oldpass.getText().toString();
             final String vnewpass=newpass.getText().toString();

            sdomain=getIntent().getExtras().getString("domain");
            ssubdomain=getIntent().getExtras().getString("subdomian");
            sprofession=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profession");
            sbranch=getIntent().getExtras().getString("branch");
            srollno=getIntent().getExtras().getString("rollno");
            spass=getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass");

            change_password cp= new change_password(sdomain,ssubdomain,sprofession,sbranch,srollno,spass,vnewpass,voldpass);


        }

}

package com.example.sdl;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class change_password {

    FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    private  String domain;
    private String subdomain,profession,branch,rollno,pass,newpass,oldpass;

    public change_password() {
    }

    public change_password( String domain,  String subdomain,  String profession,  String branch,  String rollno,  String pass,  String newpass,  String  oldpass) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.subdomain = subdomain;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.pass = pass;
        this .newpass=newpass;
        this.oldpass=   oldpass;

        DatabaseReference ref=database.getReference();


      ref.child(domain).child(subdomain).child(profession).child(branch).child(rollno).child("password").setValue(newpass);
    }




    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public String getSubdomain() {
        return subdomain;
    }

    public void setSubdomain(String subdomain) {
        this.subdomain = subdomain;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getNewpass() {
        return newpass;
    }

    public void setNewpass(String newpass) {
        this.newpass = newpass;
    }

    public String getOldpass() {
        return oldpass;
    }

    public void setOldpass(String oldpass) {
        this.oldpass = oldpass;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited out the "ASAP" remark. As noted in comments, this is rude and will be counter-productive here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You are definitely passing in a null parameter from the method change_password(String....vars), go to where you invoke that method and whatever parameters may be null

Comment: 1. You are getting `intent` values at runtime which is getting at some point. 2. get your intent value at the very beginning and then pass the values to the next activity. and Finally, I don't know why are you using too many putextra values into each activity, If you need te same values into each activity then use interface or you can save your values to SharedPreferances and get it from where ever you want. Hope you understand.